# Let H be a subgroup of $G$, then the center of $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is a true or false problem and answer is said to be False but I'm trying to figure out how it is so. All I know is that, by definition the center of a group $G$ is:

$Z(G)$={$g\in G|gx=xg$ , for all $x$ in $G$}

where the center is a subgroup of $G$. However, I'm lost when it comes to the center of the subgroup $H$ or in other words $Z(H)$ and it's relation to $Z(G)$ which leads to the answer. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Take $G = \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, and $H$ the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices (that is, $(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix})$). Then $H$ is abelian, but not in the center of $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the only relation you have in general is that $Z(G) \cap H \le Z(H)$.

But as the other examples have shown, if you take any non-trivial, centerless group $G$ (that is, a group with $Z(G) = \{1\}$), and choose $1 \ne a \in G$, the subgroup $H = \langle a \rangle \ne \{ 1 \}$ will be cyclic, thus abelian, and thus equal to its own centre, so $Z(H) \ne \{ 1\}$.

Answer (score 7):

The statement is false. Counterexample: $G = S_3$, $H = \langle (1\ 2) \rangle$. Here $\operatorname{Z}(G) = 1$ but $\operatorname{Z}(H) = H$.